# Longest word conundrum

Tags: word, language

The longest word in the English language is the name of a Welsh town.

> Can you spell it?

Comment: There is an [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/169/) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is the answer:

> it

?

> the guess was based on the tags and by how you separated the lines

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer:

> Yes... I can spell it. (the question was if I could spell it or not)

Now as to prove it..

> **it** ==> `i` followed by`t`, is how it is spelled.

It's because:

> I'm asked to spell IT, not the longest word in the English language